# Syntax for [label: string]: number type when received as parameter?

Tags: typescript

Here is an example of an IPriceMap:

```
{
  13123-1231: 2
  2342-343: 1
}
```

It has the interface:

```
interface IPriceMap {
    [productId: string]: number;
}
```

I want to receive it as a parameter but can't refer to IPriceMap. How can I achieve that? See the question mark below.

```
public async updatePrices(quotationId: Id, priceMap: ?) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: "but can't refer to IPriceMap" --- this needs further elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you can't use `IPriceMap`.

But you can use an inline type of necessary:

```
public async updatePrices(quotationId: Id, priceMap: {[productId: string]: number}) {
    // ...
}
```

Or just declare a type for it:

```
// Stand-in for IPriceMap
declare type MyPriceMap = {
  [productId: string]: number
}

class X {
    public async updatePrices(quotationId: Id, priceMap: MyPriceMap) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It really shouldn't be necessary, though, and it's poor practice (since changing `IPriceMap` means the type above will become wrong).

Or, of course, `any`:

```
public async updatePrices(quotationId: Id, priceMap: any) {
    // ...
}
```

...which at least has the advantage that if `IPriceMap` changes, it's not actually incorrect, just...vague.